# Connect titanium android with wcf rest

Tags: android, wcf, rest, titanium

please share :how can connect   titanium android application with  Wcf Rest  ???... sample code,or tutorial,or good link or some suggestion or share your experience .....i am new to mobile application.....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kitchen Sink has a few examples of using XHR and the networkclient.

Mobile Tuts+ has a good walk thru on using Titanium to consume Twitter.  You should be able to use this as a starting point.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/appcelerator-using-json-to-build-a-twitter-client/